# Why can't I compile my Erlang code

Tags: erlang

I have single file in my folder:

```
test.erl
```

But I can't compile my module:

```
test.erl:8: syntax error before: 
test.erl:2: function area/1 undefined
```

This is how I try to compile my **test.erl** file:

```
erlc ./test.erl
```

**test.erl** contains these lines:

```
-module(test).
-export([area/1]).

% comment

area({triangle, A, B, C}) ->
    S = (A + B + C) / 2,
    math:sqrt(S*(S-A)*(S-B)*(S-C));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For those wondering about the mathematical meaning: Vitaly tried to implement [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_Heron's_formula)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ended the definition of the `area` with a semicolon. A complete definition must end with a dot, though.